# angular js too much recursion error on $apply() call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

Whenever I trigger the `$apply` on my scopes, Too much recursion error is being thrown.

console output:

```
Error: too much recursion
isArray@file://.../lib/angular.js:355:10
copy@file://.../lib/angular.js:551:9
copy@file://.../lib/angular.js:546:23
copy@file://.../lib/angular.js:563:28
...

Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@file://.../lib/angular.js:7756:19
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@file://.../lib/angular.js:7926:13
```

Comment: used on `AngularJS v1.0.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Too much recursion error

**If** cause by `copy` method on the angularjs, your data has a circular reference to each other.

in example:

```
// you define your objects
var lot = new Lot();
var car = new Car();

// you assign create a relation to it
car.assign( lot );
lot.assign( car );

// lets assume that the data on the objects are like this
car; // {'lot':lot}
lot; // {'car':car}
```

When the `$apply()` is triggered, whether you call it or the angular call it, it will call to `copy` method somewhere.

What happens to `copy` is copying every attribute and anything it could copy. When apply to our data above, it will recur forever if not stopped.

This causes the browser to stop it and raises the `Too much recursion` error.

**Solution:**

Get only the data you need for rendering your element.
pass only to the data needed.

using our sample code above,

```
var reduced = {'plate':car.get_plate(),'lot':car.get_lot_location()};
my_scope.addCar( reduced );
```

---

*tip to self:* use unminified versions of library when debugging. :)